# IF function in LibreOffice5 Calc

Tags: libreoffice-calc

In have a formula in a cell `=IF(M1="i")` and it returns `TRUE` while string `i` is in a cell `M1`. However, if I write `IF(M1="i",yes,no)` or `IF(M1="i";yes;no)`I get `#NAME?` error. Why is that?

I found [here](https://help.libreoffice.org/Calc/Logical_Functions#IF) clear instructions:

> IF(Test; ThenValue; OtherwiseValue)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this: `=IF(M1="i"; "yes"; "no")`

Comment: Stupid me. I worte numbers without quotation mark and it didn't work. In the example on LO site it works with numbers without quotations ?!

Comment: It works for numbers without quotes - but not strings. You need quotes around strings.  This works: =IF(M1="i"; 42; 20)

Comment: It didn't work for me, because the cell was formated as `boolean value` and with `=IF(M1="i"; 42; 20)` showed only `TRUE`. When I changed cell format to `all` or `number`, it worked and showed a number. Thanks.